# JSON to update table cell

Tags: jquery, json, cell

This was working when I had `input type=text id="class_fee_cell"` in the fee amount cell, but what I really want is to have a cell value that the user cannot change, but I want to update the fee amount when a different fee type is selected. 
I can't see why this isn't working? (that 'form_options' is a function that builds the select box of fee types. JSON queries for the amount of the fee selected).

HTML- (two cells on the same row of a table)

```
<td id="class_fee_cell">
    <?= html($class['class_fee']) ?>
</td>                         
<td> 
    <select name="students[<?php echo $i ?>][fee_id]" class="fee_id_select" id="<?php echo $i ?>" style="width: 10em">
        <option></option>
        <?= form_options($fee_options, array('selected'=>$class['fee_id']) ) ?>
        <br><br>
    </select>                
</td>
```

jQuery: (JSON gets fee amount based on fee type selected, but the fee amount cell in the table is not being updated.)

```
$(".fee_id_select").live("change",function ()
{
    var $fee = $(this).closest('tr').find('#class_fee_cell');           
    jQuery.getJSON('get_fee_json.php',
         {
             'id': this.value
         },
         function (data, textStatus)
         {
             var fee = data || {};
             $fee.val(fee.fee_amount || '');    
         }
    );                                                                   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$fee.val(fee.fee_amount || '');`

you can try 
`$fee.text(fee.fee_amount || '');`

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Doh! see it now... $fee.html(fee.fee_amount || ''); (not $fee.val(...

Thank you anyway!